# ¿Cómo poner número de linea a un RichTextBox en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un RichTextBox el cual usare como un editor de código pero quiero agregar el número de linea en la parte izquierda. ¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias implementaciones

[Creating Line Numbers for RichTextBox in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/creating-line-numbers-for-richtextbox-in-c-sharp)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La magia esta aqui

```
public void AddLineNumbers()  
{  
    // create & set Point pt to (0,0)    
    Point pt = new Point(0, 0);  
    // get First Index & First Line from richTextBox1    
    int First_Index = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pt);  
    int First_Line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(First_Index);  
    // set X & Y coordinates of Point pt to ClientRectangle Width & Height respectively    
    pt.X = ClientRectangle.Width;  
    pt.Y = ClientRectangle.Height;  
    // get Last Index & Last Line from richTextBox1    
    int Last_Index = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pt);  
    int Last_Line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(Last_Index);  
    // set Center alignment to LineNumberTextBox    
    LineNumberTextBox.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;  
    // set LineNumberTextBox text to null & width to getWidth() function value    
    LineNumberTextBox.Text = "";  
    LineNumberTextBox.Width = getWidth();  
    // now add each line number to LineNumberTextBox upto last line    
    for (int i = First_Line; i <= Last_Line + 2; i++)  
    {  
        LineNumberTextBox.Text += i + 1 + "\n";  
    }  
}
```

Basicamente tiene dos `RichTextBox`:

- uno de nombre `richTextBox1` que es donde visualizas el codigo
- el otro `LineNumberTextBox` que esta al costado donde visualizas los numeros